# Tsql group by clause with exceptions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a problem with a query.

This is the data (order by Timestamp):

```
Data
    ID  Value   Timestamp
    1   0       2001-1-1
    2   0       2002-1-1
    3   1       2003-1-1
    4   1       2004-1-1
    5   0       2005-1-1
    6   2       2006-1-1
    7   2       2007-1-1
    8   2       2008-1-1
```

I need to extract distinct values and the first occurance of the date. The exception here is that I need to group them only if not interrupted with a new value in that timeframe.
So the data I need is:

```
ID  Value   Timestamp
1   0       2001-1-1
3   1       2003-1-1
5   0       2005-1-1
6   2       2006-1-1
```

I've made this work by a complicated query, but am sure there is an easier way to do it, just cant think of it. Could anyone help?

This is what I started with - probably could work with that. This is a query that should locate when a value is changed.

```
  > SELECT * FROM Data d1 join Data d2 ON d1.Timestamp < d2.Timestamp and
    > d1.Value <> d2.Value
```

It probably could be done with a good use of row_number clause but cant manage it.

Comment: Show us the query, it would be best for you to let us help you improving it

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? There are ways to do this in 2012 version that are not an option in 2005 or 2000 versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```
declare @T table (ID int, Value int, Timestamp date)
insert into @T(ID,  Value,   Timestamp) values
(1,   0,       '20010101'),
(2,   0,       '20020101'),
(3,   1,       '20030101'),
(4,   1,       '20040101'),
(5,   0,       '20050101'),
(6,   2,       '20060101'),
(7,   2,       '20070101'),
(8,   2,       '20080101')
```

Query:

```
;With OrderedValues as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER By TimeStamp) as rn --TODO - specific columns better than *
    from @T
), Firsts as (
    select
        ov1.* --TODO - specific columns better than *
    from
        OrderedValues ov1
            left join
        OrderedValues ov2
            on
                ov1.Value = ov2.Value and
                ov1.rn = ov2.rn + 1
    where
        ov2.ID is null
)
select * --TODO - specific columns better than *
from Firsts
```

I didn't rely on the `ID` values being sequential and without gaps. If that's the situation, you can omit `OrderedValues` (using the table and `ID` in place of `OrderedValues` and `rn`). The second query simply finds rows where there isn't an immediate preceding row with the same `Value`.

Result:

```
ID          Value       Timestamp  rn
----------- ----------- ---------- --------------------
1           0           2001-01-01 1
3           1           2003-01-01 3
5           0           2005-01-01 5
6           2           2006-01-01 6
```

You can order by `rn` if you need the results in this specific order.